# Stack Overflow error while performing Search in Binary search tree

Tags: stack-overflow, binary-search-tree

I am getting a stack overflow error while performing a Binary Search on a tree. I think it has a valid recursive termination condition, but I am not sure.

```java
TreeNode Find(TreeNode tree, int value) {
  if((tree.val == value) || tree==null) 
    return tree; 
  else if(value < tree.val) 
    return Find(tree.left, value); 
  else 
    return Find(tree.right, value); 
}
```

Comment: 1) you should probably do tree == null || tree.val == value (so if it is null, it doesn't crash 2) Are you sure your BST is a tree and didn't somehow end up being a cycle?  (Suggest printing out values as you traverse)

Comment: I thought was a post about a bug in StackOverflow site XD.

Comment: I added an answer, balancing a binary tree should be asked in a separate question :) wellcome to stackoveflow site :) don't forget to accept my answer (green check mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is elsewhere (your function is almost perfectly correct):

**Your tree is not balanced!**

what you have to make correct is the insertion function. A trivial insertion function will just create a linked list like tree because if you insert elements in "ascending" order, they are always added only to "left" or to right.

The stack has limited space, so if you have a balanced tree it can have 4 billions nodes it will still have a maximum height of 32. But if your tree is unbalanced even with few nodes (1000) it can go in stack overflow.

I also suggest to first checking for null (this is not your problem, take it as a free bug fix)

```
if(tree==null || tree.val == value )
```

Comment: I had already tried the null thing but I guess the tree is question is not balanced after all. Thanks